# What force could theoretically redirect the Higgs field?

Tags: higgs, faster-than-light, bosons

I’d just like to point out I am by no means a physics expert, or indeed a particularly knowledgable nerd on this subject. I am a minor and a wannabe sci-fi writer who is trying to come up with an idea for FTL travel, and who would like it to at least give a nod towards known physics. So, here goes.

The Higgs field is a field of energy thought to encompass every square inch of the universe. It is made up of Higgs bosons; particles which deliver their mass to every particle they come into contact with. This prevents anything other than massless particles (like photons) from reaching or exceeding the speed of light. Trying to do so can be likened to trying to wade through treacle.

My reasoning was that, if it was possible to redirect localised patches of Higgs bosons and create a region of boson-less Space, then within that space it would be possible (of an object) to reach the speed of light without gaining mass, or even to exceed it, potentially allowing for interstellar travel.

Is this, at its heart, possible? That is, is it possible to redirect Higgs bosons in such a way?

Comment: The Higgs field is part of the mechanism that gives particles mass, but it's not the reason you cannot exceed the speed of light - that's fundamental to the structure of spacetime.  Special and general relativity both result in a "speed limit" in the universe and they have no quantum theory built-in.

Comment: The Higgs field explains *some* mass, not all of it, not even most of it.